Isn’t asking for resources off-topic?
I saw this question just now, and was confused. Isn’t asking about how to learn things off topic, according to the site guide? And why was this question on Meta?

It was on meta precisely because it is off topic on the main site. Whether it's strictly allowed on meta, I don't know, but people tend to be more relaxed about it. My guess is that the reasoning would go something like: it's off topic on the main site because it will lead to a lot of low quality opinion based questions and answers, but there isn't much traffic on the meta site, so the occasional question does no harm. I imagine the relaxed attitude would quickly change if meta started to be flooded with such questions.

OK, thanks. I was confused about meta because they asked a “normal” question, not one about something being on topic.
